# Java SSLException and detecting the cause of it

Tags: java, exception, ssl

I obtain a DataInputStream from an SSLSocket, and read bytes from it. Now, sometimes I get a connection timeout, and I need to notify the user about this.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x64f40f88: I/O error during system call, Connection timed out
```

Also, sometimes I get "Connection reset by peer", and I need to identify that too.

I am currently simply checking if the exception's message contains the string "timed out" or "reset by peer", but this feels kind of nasty. However, it looks to me that this string checking is the only way to obtain more information about the cause?

Comment: Most SSLExceptions have 'cause' attributes.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how I could've missed the getCause()-method... However, in my case it seems to just return null, so I've little choice but to check the String.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing and I can't find the root cause of it. My Exceptions are raised with a null cause.